# Why does the Empire need Leia to give them the location of the rebel base?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one, continuity

Given the number of rebels they captured at the end of *Rogue One* who came straight from Yavin, why did Vader and Tarkin need to go to such lengths to extract that information from Leia? Just what happened to the rebel fleet after the end of *Rogue One*?

Comment: Maybe they all kept schtum.

Comment: Weren't they all blown up, the ones that didn't get away?

Comment: The flagship was clearly intact, as Tantive IV ejected from it.

Comment: Maybe Vader killed them all? Didn't look like he let many survive.

Comment: True. He killed the captain of Tantive IV with no consideration for extracting information. But then, many other soldiers were captured...

Comment: It's just a continuity error by the Rogue One makers, no more no less.

Comment: Were really all of the fleet on Yavin IV? Rebel organizations work in cells. Only high ranking members know all the locations and only they might know about the other cells and the fleet is likely staging somewhere in space. The target of the Death Star is the leadership of the Rebel Alliance (Mon Mothma, Jan Dodanna, etc.) they would surely not share their wherabout with just every rebel all the time as that would be too risky. The admiral abord the flagship knew (for he was there) as did most of the Rogue One team on Scarif, but the later all died and we don't know about the admiral.

Comment: @Buzz: I don't think we can call it a continuity error, given that we also see crew from the *Tantive IV* captured alive in *A New Hope*. If it's a plot hole, it's one that both films share, not a lack of continuity between them.

Comment: @TimPederick Yeah, no.  The crew just knows they are gong to Alderan.  There's a reason why Vader wants the passengers alive.

Answer (score 12):

Keep in mind that the Empire doesn't *know* all these rebels came from the base on Yavin.  For all the Empire knows, they could have come from all over the galaxy, meeting at a pre-arranged point for a large pre-planned mission, without ever knowing the location of the primary rebel base.

They go after Leia because *time is a factor.*  Leia is a known public figure, which means a couple of things:

- as a high-ranking official in galactic society, and presumably in the rebellion, there's a better chance that she actually knows where the base is.
- they have leverage over her automatically - to wit, they know which planet she calls home.

If standard "interrogation" techniques don't yield fruit they can (and do) threaten her family.  Indeed, the whole planet.  This is a heavy-handed approach, but it's their best bet at finding the location they need *quickly.*  And Leia is the highest profile captive they have, upon whom to use these tactics.

Sure, they could've done the same thing with each and every faceless rebel grunt they caught, but they would've had to spend time figuring out who these people are, where their homes and families are, etc, etc.  They were probably smart enough not to carry (legitimate) identification tags on the mission, so this process is going to be more than just typing one name per captive into the Star Wars equivalent of Google Maps.  Plus, they only have one Death Star, so they'd have to travel to each and every planet they found to pull the old "tell us or we'll blow up your home planet" stunt.

Even after all that, the rebels could lie.  (Indeed, Leia *does lie* even though they have her dead to rights.)  They could break under torture and just tell the Imperials whatever planet they seem to want to hear.  Given how big a galaxy is, it could take *years* to run down all those leads and figure out which, if any, were legitimate.  During that time, the rebels surely would have relocated their base of operations anyway.

Comment: Not sure a agree that threatening your home planet should be just enough to break the camel's back if  threatening a different world with ten billion people isn't.   These are the good guys.   They aren't supposed to be selfish that way.

Comment: Mmm. But why not simply have Vader mind probe or mind trick some captive Rebel soldier for information?

Comment: Well, we know the mind trick only works on the weak-minded. I would assume the same limitation applies to "mind probes" (not so familiar with material beyond the movies)... Deciding to stand up and fight for freedom against a powerful regime, in the face of overwhelming odds, takes a certain amount of willpower. Not to mention going through whatever trials the Rebellion employs to test applicants - if they accepted everyone who walked through the door it would be easy-peasy for the Empire to infiltrate their ranks. So, maybe the average rebel isn't as easy to influence as the average ST.

Answer (score 1):

That the Empire needs to question people at all and aren't trying to dig the information out of the ship's log or navicomputer says to me they've at least taken some basic precautions to protect it's location.
In all likelihood, none of those soldiers actually knew the location. Sure, they may have been there, be able to describe a jungle moon orbiting a gas giant and the ancient ruins, but that could be one of thousands of obscure corners of the galaxy or some entirely uncharted world. If the rebellion had any sense the name "Yavin 4" would be kept classified and the co-ordinates kept only by high ranking members.

Captain Antillies may have known, but Vader killed him trying to get him to talk about the location of the plans (his immediate priority at the time), hence later: "now she is my only link."

Answer (score 0):

This will probably get downvoted, but honest answer is **they didn't need Leia to learn location of Rebel (base)s** . Any decent military here on Earth is capable to process dozens of POWs at the same time. Ruthless galactic war machine like Empire would have lots of professional interrogators coupled with torture droids to extract information. Not every Rebel is strong-minded like Leia, some of them would certainly break more easily. In real life, any guerrilla movement must not stay in one place for too long. Rebels of course knew that, so they would relocate periodically (Dantooine->Yavin->Hoth) . Why they didn't leave Yavin earlier after Battle of Scariff is not entirely clear.

One thing to note, Imperials still needed Leia to get plans for Death Star, but whole plot of letting her escape to learn location of main Rebel base is now completely illogical, after Rouge One retcon.